# Getting chosen project type in an MBS custom page (New C Project Wizard)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, wizard, project-types

I have searched everywhere and asked this question on the cdt forum but to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have extended the New C Project wizard using org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.ui.newWizardPages. I have created several custom pages for entering user parameters and all works well.

All I want to do is get the project type from the new C project wizard's first page.

I have seen, when stepping through CDTConfigWizardPage (the class of the new C Project wizard's 2nd page):

```
  IProjectType pt = handler.getProjectType();
```

where handler is the MBSWizardHandler passed to the CDTConfigWizardPage's constructor.

How can I get this handler in one of my custom pages?

Thanks in advance,

Antony

Comment: How did you add the custom pages? I added `org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.ui.newWizardPages` to the extensions and created `MyPages extends MBSCustomPage` but how do I add my pages to the wizard?